# Prove or disprove: $S_{10} = \langle (1,3),(1,2, ... ,10) \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated, permutation-cycles

Prove or disprove: $S_{10} = \langle (1,3),(1,2, ... ,10) \rangle$

---

I know that $S_{10}=\langle (1,2) , (1,2,...,10) \rangle$. I tried to use this fact to prove the above but failed. It made me think it is not true, but I couldn't find an explanation. Any thoughts?

Comment: Shaun's comment (now deleted?) was correct. There's nothing special about the labels $1, 2, \ldots, 10$. It's the structure (of the permutations) that matters.

Comment: As a hint, the answer to the question is no. Consider the action of the group generated on the partition of $\{1,\ldots,10\}$ into even and odd numbers. (It is known as an imprimitive group.)

Comment: @M.Vinay It is still not a trivial consequence, as the transposition in one case transposes two elements which are adjacent in the cyclic permutation, but in the other case they are non-adjacent. That is a difference which turns out to matter.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, and I thought I'd seen a way of generating a cycle of length $10$ that maps $1$ to $3$, using the two given permutations. That was just a stupid miscalculation. If that were correct, then $(1\ 3)$ along with that cycle would be equivalent to $(1\ 2)$ along with the original cycle and so would generate $S_{10}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the action of your group on $\{1,2,\ldots,10\}^2=\{[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],\ldots[10,10]\}$. (I'm using brackets for the ordered pairs, since parentheses indicate cycles in this topic.) The action is just coordinate-wise.

Of your two elements, $(1,2,\ldots,10)$ takes $[\text{odd},\text{odd}]$ to $[\text{even},\text{even}]$ and vice versa.  The other one, $(1,3)$ takes any $[\text{odd},\text{odd}]$ to some possibly different $[\text{odd},\text{odd}]$, and leaves $[\text{even},\text{even}]$ unmoved.

Therefore this group has no elements that could take $[\text{odd},\text{odd}]$ to $[\text{odd},\text{even}]$. In particular, it cannot take $[3,1]$ to $[3,2]$. But if the group were the full $S_{10}$, it would have the transposition $(1,2)$, which does take $[3,1]$ to $[3,2]$. So the group is missing $(1,2)$ among many other elements of $S_{10}$.

Comment: It seems to me that you are making this unnecessarily complicated. Why are looking at the action on ordered pairs rather than on singletons? The $10$-cycle interchanges odd and even numbers, whereas $(1,3)$ maps odds to odds and evens to evens.

Comment: @DerekHoltIf you can make the argument based on singletons, that would be great. But note that there is no contradiction with simply moving $1$ to $2$. The 10-cycle can do that. The contradiction I arrive at is moving $1$ to $2$ while at the same time leaving $3$ unmoved. I found it more concise to get to that contradiction using pairs.

Comment: OK, but the idea of a subgroup of ${\rm Sym}(X)$ preserving a partition of $X$ (in this case the partition into even and odd numbers) is a basic concept in the theory of permutation groups. Transitive goups with that property are called imprimitive and embed into a wreath product. In this case, the subgroup generated is the full group that preserves this partition, which is $S_5 \wr S_2 \cong (S_5 \times S_5) \rtimes S_2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thata's all fine, using several vocabulary terms and a little bit of notation familiar to "specialists" (not the right word, but for lack of a better term). I was just trying to post an answer that might be more immediately accessible to a student beginning to learn about $S_n$ and a possible way to generate it. I have no way to know if OP is familiar with "transitive", "imprimitive", "wreath product", and other things. I think I posted an answer accessible to a beginner with this type of question.